# How to install Anoconda properly

Tags: python, path, anaconda

I have installed python 3.9.6 sometime back and would like to use the Anaconda libraries. When I try to access the libraries of Anaconda (I have downloaded) through python or Ipython I receive the error "no module found". I think that this error is regarding my PATH to python and Anaconda. Is my hypothesis correct, and how can I fix it?

Best,
Hunter

Comment: If you share some details of the library installation process you followed, if they needed separate installation, and the code that threw the no module found error, it would be easier for us to diagnose and debug for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me. To clarify, I cannot access the modules of anoconda such as numpy in the command terminal. However, If I use the anaconda prompt I have no problem. Here is where I have downloaded the programs: 1. Python - C:\\Users\\name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39       2.  Anoconda - C:\\Users\\name\\anoconda3    This may not give you the best indication of my problem, but perhaps you know some resources where I can learn about the interaction of the terminal with program files, modules, and how to use pip properly. Best, Hunter.

Comment: Please ignore my misspelling of anaconda